# NoMethodError in PostsController#create undefined method `body'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Whenever I try to save the post, this error is showing up.

[image]

Here's my `new.html.erb` file.

```
<div id="page_wrapper">
 <h1>New Post</h1>
  <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errors">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this post from saving:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label :date %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :date %><br>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label :time %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :time %><br>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label :location %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :location %><br>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Here's my `show.html.erb` file.

```
<div id="page_wrapper">
<h1 class="title">
    <%= @post.title %>
</h1>

<p class="date">
    Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
</p>

<p class="time">
    <%= @post.time %>
</p>

<p class="location">
    <%= @post.location %>
</p>
</div>
```

Here's my `posts_controller.rb` file.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')      
 end

 def new    
    @post = Post.new    
 end

 def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save   
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
 end

 def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])      
 end

 private
 def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :location)
 end
end
```

Hers's my `routes.rb` file

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root "posts#index"
 end
```

Comment: share your schema.rb

Comment: hi @pavan my schema.rb looks like this, ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160812052026) do

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "date"
    t.string   "time"
    t.text     "location"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end

Comment: @ArunKumar I have my error screenshot above, it gives me NoMethodError in PostsController#create
undefined method `body' for #<Post:0x007f3b81a787f8>    whenever i save the post

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Did you add any validations for `body` in `post.rb`?

Comment: yes, I have @ArunKumar, here's it is...class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
 validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
 validates :body,  presence: true
end

Comment: thnx a lot..really appreciate your help @ArunKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added a validation for `body` in your `post.rb`. But you don't have the field `body` in your `posts` table.

So, when `@post.create` is invoked, all the validations defined in `post.rb` are run and since you don't have a `body` field, you were getting an `Undefined method 'body' for Post` error.

To solve it, remove the validation for `body` in `post.rb`

Remove the following line

```
validates :body, presence: true
```

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :location)
```

You required `:body` but in your form you have `title, date, time and location`.

Remove it and make sure you have this attributes in your strong params like this:

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :date, :time, :location)
```